# How to ignore problematic tokens in xelatex

Tags: xetex, errors

I work with a lot of OCRed text and almost always there are symbols that require escaping/marking to be interpreted correctly in latex. E.g. the `&` symbol.

I would like to be able to see the output (pdf) without having to fix all errors.

Is it possible to make xelatex ignore all problematic tokens/words and continue typesetting the document with only the correct tokens?

Comment: `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode`?

Answer (score 1):

when reading plain text you can make all characters normal

If your plain OCR'ed text is in foo.txt then

```
{\lowercase{
\catcode`\&=12
\catcode`\%=12
\cactcode`\\=12
\catcode`\~=12
\catcode`\_=12
\catcode`\^=12
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode`\}=12
}
\input{foo.txt}
}
}
```

Will input the file with even `\` acting as a normal character, normal tex rules will be restored at the end of the file.